# Is waitpid() an atomic operation in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, system-calls

For example, in the parent process, I forked a child process and wait on the child process:

```
int main() {
     setSignal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler)
     while(1) {
        // fork some child processes
        myForkFunction()

        waitpid(-1, &status, 0)
     }
}
```

Moreover, I have a SIGCHLD signal handler:

```
void
sigchld_handler(int sig) {
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
       // Reap zombie processes
    }    
}
```

As can be seen, `waitpid()` appears both in the `main()` function and in the `sigchld_handler()` function. I was wondering whether `waitpid` can be interrupted by `SIGCHLD`. If it can be interrupted by `SIGCHLD`, what will happen then?

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Why are you using `WUNTRACED` instead of `0` or `WNOHANG`?  `WUNTRACED` is a very specialized condition — POSIX [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html)
says: _WUNTRACED
    The status of any child processes specified by pid that are stopped, and whose status has not yet been reported since they stopped, shall also be reported to the requesting process._  (There's an 'also' in there that I missed on first reading, but even so, messing with stopped/traced processes is unusual.)

Comment: Yeah, `WUNTRACED` is very odd and probably not what OP wants...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: You fixed it wrong. You should have changed it to `WNOHANG` (not `0`). `0` will cause your signal handler to block if you have a child that's not finished yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX specification for [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) says in part:

> If _POSIX_REALTIME_SIGNALS is defined, and the implementation queues the SIGCHLD signal, then if `wait()` or `waitpid()` returns because the status of a child process is available, any pending SIGCHLD signal associated with the process ID of the child process shall be discarded. Any other pending SIGCHLD signals shall remain pending.
>
> Otherwise, if SIGCHLD is blocked, if `wait()` or `waitpid()` return because the status of a child process is available, any pending SIGCHLD signal shall be cleared unless the status of another child process is available.
>
> For all other conditions, it is unspecified whether child status will be available when a SIGCHLD signal is delivered.

The third of the quoted paragraphs seems to imply that you're treading on thin ice.  It doesn't mention 'implementation defined' or similar — unspecified means that the standard says nothing about what shall happen and you may or may not get any information from the implementation-specific documentation.

There is a lot of (very densely worded) information in the POSIX specification.  There are also some examples, and a rationale — which mentions [`sigwait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html) and [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwaitinfo.html).  It is worth reading the whole of the `waipid()` page.  You should probably also read about [Signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) too — more dense reading.  (One of these days, I'll do it, too — when I need to know about bits of signals that I haven't covered before.)

---

Why are you using `WUNTRACED` instead of `0` or `WNOHANG`?  `WUNTRACED` is a very specialized condition — POSIX says:

> WUNTRACED
> The status of any child processes specified by pid that are stopped, and whose status has not yet been reported since they stopped, shall also be reported to the requesting process.

Similar comments apply to `WCONTINUED`. Those two flags are useful when you need them, but you very seldom need them.

I suggest you should normally use either `0` or `WNOHANG` in the third argument to `waitpid()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I was reading CSAPP book before asking the question. It seems that POSIX specification is a better place to look for these informations. Thanks!

Comment: I went poking at [The Linux Programming Interface](https://smile.amazon.com/Linux-Programming-Interface-System-Handbook/dp/1593272200) and didn't find anything directly relevant in chapter 'Monitoring Child Processes' which covers a lot of material about SIGCHLD and `waitpid()` — or in a couple of other places in the same book that I looked at.  That's far from a definitive 'it is not covered', but it is indicative that it probably isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the sense that only one of them can succeed for a given child process; if the signal handler interrupts the one in `main`, then after the signal handler returns, the child will already have been reaped and the call in `main` will fail.

With that said, however, it's bad practice to write code like this. There should be a single place you handle reaping of a given child process, and usually a signal handler is a very bad choice because it's global and it would have to be aware of all possible child processes your program might have finishing, *and have a way to communicate those results to the proper parts of your program*.

Instead, it's generally better to monitor the termination of child processes via `poll` on a pipe to/from the child process, and only `waitpid` after you know it's terminated, or to perform blocking `waitpid` from a thread whose only job is to wait for the child.